# How to load a @Profile service in spring-test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

How can I load a `@Profile` component in a `spring-test`, without having to explicit launch that profile as startup profile?

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev1")
public class MvcInterceptor extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    //adding a custom interceptor
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MappedInterceptor("/customer", new CustomerInterceptor()));
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
    }

}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
//@ActiveProfiles("dev1") //I don't want spring to load the full profile chain
public class SpringTest {
    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        mvc.perform(get(...))...;
    }
}
```

Question: how can I load the `MvcInterceptor` without using `@ActiveProfiles("dev1")` on the testclass?

Because, `dev1` profile would imply many more resources being set up, which I won't need for that test. I just want to load the `MvcInterceptor`, but without having to launch the full profile.

Impossible?

Comment: for MvcInterceptor class you can set `@Profile("dev1", "test")`. This way only this class is loaded for test profile also

Comment: While this could work, I'd like to prevent polluting my normal classes with test-specific code...

Comment: you can try loading specific classes with `@ContextConfiguration`, but as long as you have `@Profile` on that class, spring will not load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by initializing the a `Bean` in a static inner `@TestConfiguration` class.

```
public class SpringTest {
    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public MvcInterceptor interceptor() {
            return new MvcInterceptor();
        }
    }
}
```

Though `MvcInterceptor` is `@Profile` depending, it will be wired for the test.